# Forwarding auth token through API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My team is in the process of migrating away from directly read/writes to and from firebase RTDB for our mobile and web app, to a more classic server/client model.

In doing so, I wanted to see if there was a mechanism to forward a users firebase auth token through our server API into the call to the DB. The purpose of this is so that my security rules could apply to the auth token of the user request, and I wouldn't have to write a layer to manage user data access, instead relying on firebase to handle it for me.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to firebase to check before user accessing the data. In that case, you can use firebase getIdToken like below

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(); // which returns promise.
```

attach this token to the http headers and then in API Call check the token like below

```
const validateFirebaseIdToken = (request, response, next) => {
cors(request, response, () => {
    if (!request.headers || !request.headers.authorization) {
        return response.status(403).send("Sorry! You're not authorized to access this url");
    }
    const token = request.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
    return firebase.auth().verifyIdToken(token).then(decodedId => {
        request.user = {};
        request.user.uid = decodedId.uid;
        return next();
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return response.status(403).send("Sorry! You're not authorized to access this url");
     });
  });
}
```

This is how you need to check the firebase id token with the API call. Hope this gives you an idea. Feel free to ask if you any doubts

Comment: Hey I understand how to pass it through and verify. I wanted to see if there was anyway to pass the token into a call to db.ref().once('value').then(s => s.val()), and see if that user would be able to access that data based on our security rules.

Comment: I hope there is no way you can do something like that. May be you can ask firebase developers

Comment: This is incredibly helpful @MuruGan, Enjoy an upvote